# How to import package properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have some projects I try to split up for easier management. Therefor I moved some parts that are used by different applications into modules rather than copying files around.

Right now I have the following structure for my modules (every module has its own docs and tests):

```
/projects
  /module1
    __init__.py
    run_tests.py
    /docs
      ...
    /module1
      __init__.py
      module1.py
    /tests
      __init__.py
      module1_test.py
  /module2
    ...
```

Now I got myself the "main app" directory laid out in the same manner:

```
/projects
  run_app.py
  run_tests.py
  /docs
    ...
  /app
    __init__.py
    app.py
    module1 <-- Link to the module1 repository
  /tests
    __init__.py
    app_tests.py
```

All my `__init__.py` files are empty at the moment and I do not know how to write a proper import statements in my `app.py` file. Since there is only one class in module1 I don't want a hugh `import module1.module1.module1.ModuleClass` so the `ModuleClass` should be imported to "module level" so I can just do something like a `import module1.ModuleClass`. I figure I have to tweak the `__init__.py` files but all I tried broke either the tests or the whole import.

Any help would be very much appreciated and sorry for my poor explanations I am not a native speaker...

Comment: You could write a `setup.py` for each sub-module and install them as dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution myself. As always it was pretty straight forward.

I just had to add the following line in all the `__init__.py` files recursively to the top of the module.

```
from .module1 import ModuleClass
```

I will leave this here for future references if somebody might end up in the same situation.

Cheers